# Erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { com easyui

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com o framework easyui

esta hospedado no azure: http://crudeasyui.azurewebsites.net/

repositório do código: https://github.com/alexjosesilva/CrudEasyui

porém esta dando erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Cpodigo Html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Basic CRUD Application - jQuery EasyUI CRUD Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/color.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Basic CRUD Application</h2>


    <table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
            url="get_users.php"
            toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
            rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="firstname" width="50">First Name</th>
                <th field="lastname" width="50">Last Name</th>
                <th field="phone" width="50">Phone</th>
                <th field="email" width="50">Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newUser()">New User</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editUser()">Edit User</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="destroyUser()">Remove User</a>
    </div>

    <div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:400px;height:280px;padding:10px 20px"
            closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
        <div class="ftitle">User Information</div>
        <form id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input name="firstname" class="easyui-textbox" required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input name="lastname" class="easyui-textbox" required="true">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Phone:</label>
                <input name="phone" class="easyui-textbox">
            </div>
            <div class="fitem">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input name="email" class="easyui-textbox" validType="email">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="dlg-buttons">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton c6" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="saveUser()" style="width:90px">Save</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')" style="width:90px">Cancel</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url;
        function newUser(){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
            $('#fm').form('clear');
            url = 'save_user.php';
        }

        function editUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
                $('#fm').form('load',row);
                url = 'update_user.php?id='+row.id;
            }
        }
        function saveUser(){
            $('#fm').form('submit',{
                url: url,
                onSubmit: function(){
                    return $(this).form('validate');
                }
                success: function(result){
                    var result = eval('('+result+')');
                    if (result.errorMsg){
                        $.messager.show({
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.errorMsg
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        function destroyUser(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to destroy this user?',function(r){
                    if (r){
                        $.post('destroy_user.php',{id:row.id},function(result){
                            if (result.success){
                                $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                            } else {
                                $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                    title: 'Error',
                                    msg: result.errorMsg
                                });
                            }
                        },'json');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #fm{
            margin:0;
            padding:10px 30px;
        }
        .ftitle{
            font-size:14px;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding:5px 0;
            margin-bottom:10px;
            border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .fitem{
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
        .fitem label{
            display:inline-block;
            width:80px;
        }
        .fitem input{
            width:160px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

**Código Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var url;
            function newUser(){
                $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
                $('#fm').form('clear');
                url = 'save_user.php';
            }

            function editUser(){
                var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
                if (row){
                    $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
                    $('#fm').form('load',row);
                    url = 'update_user.php?id='+row.id;
                }
            }
            function saveUser(){
                $('#fm').form('submit',{
                    url: url,
                    onSubmit: function(){
                        return $(this).form('validate');
                    }
                    success: function(result){
                        var result = eval('('+result+')');
                        if (result.errorMsg){
                            $.messager.show({
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.errorMsg
                            });
                        } else {
                            $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                            $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            function destroyUser(){
                var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
                if (row){
                    $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to destroy this user?',function(r){
                        if (r){
                            $.post('destroy_user.php',{id:row.id},function(result){
                                if (result.success){
                                    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                                } else {
                                    $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                        title: 'Error',
                                        msg: result.errorMsg
                                    });
                                }
                            },'json');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        </script>
```

**Código PHP**

```
<?php
    $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
    $rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;

    $result = array();

    include "conn.php";

    $rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from users");
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);

    var_dump($row);

    $result["total"] = $row[0];
    $rs = mysql_query("select * from users limit $offset,$rows");

    $items = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
        array_push($items, $row);
    }
    $result["rows"] = $items;

    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Deve ser erro de sintaxe, mas sem o código fonte é impossível informar qualquer coisa.

Comment: já adicionei o codigo e o repositorio @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: O que é esse `eval` do resultado em `success`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss corrigi: eram os var_dumps no codigo php!!

Comment: Ainda assim esse `eval` não faz sentido.

Comment: Seu problema é a falta de uma vírgula antes de `success: function(result){` dentro da função `saveUser()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o próprio erro informa: "Uncaught SyntaxError" (erro de sintaxe), é a falta de um separador (no caso, uma vírgula) nas instâncias da função `saveUser()` antes de `success:`.

```
function saveUser(){
    $('#fm').form('submit',{
        url: url,
        onSubmit: function(){
            return $(this).form('validate');
        }
        // falta uma vírgula aqui
        success: function(result){
            var result = eval('('+result+')');
            if (result.errorMsg){
                $.messager.show({
                    title: 'Error',
                    msg: result.errorMsg
                });
            } else {
                $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
            }
        }
    });
}
```